# How to bold the pandas boxplot

Tags: pandas

This is my boxplot. When putting in the paper, the boxplot lines look very thin. I tried whiskers but it only bold part of lines. Do you know how to bold all lines in the boxplot? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which graph library you are using, but matplotlib allows you to use the one defined in `boxprops`.  See the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-py).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fake data
np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.lognormal(size=(37, 4), mean=1.5, sigma=1.75)
labels = list('ABCD')
fs = 10  # fontsize

boxprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=3, color='k')
whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=3, color='k')
capprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=3, color='k')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax.boxplot(data, boxprops=boxprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops, capprops=capprops)
ax.set_title('Custom boxprops', fontsize=fs)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was using pandas. I can pass boxprops, whiskerprops, and capprops as `*args`in pandas boxplot.  Thank you!